# Inner Product for Geometric Interpretation of Multivariate Random Vectors

Tags: probability, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra, multivariate-distribution, random-vector

I was looking into the geometric interpretation of random variables as random vectors in a vector space. The textbook I'm referring to defined $\operatorname {Cov}(X,Y)$ as the inner product for any two zero-mean RVs and claimed that it is symmetric, positive definite and bilinear. Now, I understand why this is the case for univariate random variables. But this is simply not true for multivariate random variables.

For the latter, $\operatorname {Cov}(X,Y) = \operatorname {Cov}(Y,X)^T$ given $X,$ $Y$ are multivariate RVs.

What would be a legitimate inner product for multivariate RVs then?

Answer (score 3):

**By definition,** a multivariate random variable $X$ is a measurable map from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathfrak{F}, \mathbb{P})$ into a topological vector space $\mathbb{F}$.  When $\mathbb F$ has a norm $||\ ||$ (which determines its topology), then that norm determines a norm-like function on the random variables defined by

$$||X||^2=\int_\Omega ||X(\omega)||^2\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega).\tag{*}$$

As is the case even for univariate random variables, where the dimension of $\mathbb F$ is $1,$ this can fail to be a norm because $||X||=0$ implies only that $X$ is *almost surely* zero -- but not that it is identically zero.  We can create a relevant vector space out of this by declaring two random variables to be equivalent when they are almost surely the same.  The set of *equivalence classes* of random variables is then a vector space and the quotient of on that vector space indeed is a norm.  This space is called $L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{F}).$

When $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}^n,$ you might use the usual Euclidean norm $||(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)||=\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}.$

**We are done,** because *inner products and norms are equivalent *via* the polarization identity.*  Given a normed vector space $(\mathbb{V}, ||\ ||)$ (not of characteristic $2$) and $x,y\in\mathbb V,$ define their inner product as

$$x\cdot y = \frac{1}{4}\left(||x+y||^2 - ||x-y||^2\right).$$

Conversely, any inner product $\cdot\,,$ determines a norm as

$$||x||^2 = x\cdot x.$$

These formulas invert each other, establishing the claimed one-to-one correspondence.

---

Notice that when you use the usual Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n,$ linearity of integration gives a nice formula.  Let $X = (X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ be an $n$-variate random variable and rewrite $(*)$ as

$$\begin{aligned}
||X||^2 &= \int_\Omega ||X(\omega)||^2\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) \\
&= \int_\Omega |X_1(\omega)|^2 + |X_2(\omega)|^2 + \cdots + |X_n(\omega)|^2\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega)\\
&= \int_\Omega |X_1(\omega)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) + \int_\Omega |X_2(\omega)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega) + \cdots + \int_\Omega |X_n(\omega)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}(\omega)\\
&= ||X_1||^2 + ||X_2||^2 + \cdots + ||X_n||^2.
\end{aligned}$$

In this case, the squared norm of the random variable $X$ is the sum of squares of the norms of the component (univariate) random variables.  A comparable formula for the inner product follows immediately from polarization: the inner product of two such variables is the sum of the inner products of their components *qua* univariate random variables.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the notation you've used. Could you please explain the equation (*) ? I understand most of your answer, given I understand this equation.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=LOTUS.  If that doesn't do it, look at some of [our threads on expectations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=sigma+algebra+expect*+-conditional).