# Request a geometric proof that difference of sample-means has additive variance larger than the components?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance

Request a geometric proof that difference of sample-means has additive variance larger than the components?

You are not allowed to use the formula quoted.

> In general, the variance of the sum of $\mathrm{n}$ variables is the sum of their covariances:
> $$
> \operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \operatorname{Cov}\left(X_{i}, X_{j}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{Var}\left(X_{i}\right)+2 \sum_{1 \leq i<j \leq n} \operatorname{Cov}\left(X_{i}, X_{j}\right)
> $$
> (Note: The second equality comes from the fact that $\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_{i}, X_{j}\right)=\operatorname{Var}\left(X_{j}\right)$.)

Comment: Could you rephrase your sentence. It is currently very difficult to read and it is difficult to make sense of it.

Comment: Prove Var(X-Y)=Var(X+Y) but you cannot use the formula quoted.

Comment: One solution is in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/267021/919.  Another is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122665/919.  A third is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/535435/919.  Take your pick.

Comment: Is there a geometric proof?

Comment: The polarization identity is geometry.  Covariances are squared Euclidean distances and everything ultimately comes down to the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: *"has additive variance larger than the components?"* What does this mean?

Comment: Is this question about two independent variables? Say $X$ and $Y$ are independent (so covariance is zero) then why $$\text{Var}(X-Y) = \text{Var}(X) + \text{Var}(Y)$$ instead of $$\text{Var}(X-Y) = \text{Var}(X) - \text{Var}(Y)$$ The part 'larger than the components' is unclear to me.

Comment: If $X = Y$ (ie they are fully correlated), then $\text{Var}(X-Y)=0$ and it is smaller than the components.